# IBM MQ problems with app developed in java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have an application developed in JAVA that consumes and publishes messages in IBM MQ queues, here I leave the dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId> javax.jms </groupId>
<artifactId> jms </artifactId>
<version> 1.1 </version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId> com.ibm </groupId>
<artifactId> com.ibm.mqjms </artifactId>
<version> 7.5.03 </version>
</dependency>
```

Two or three weeks ago the application started to fail with the following error:

> Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested
>   exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0091:
>   The provider factory for connection type 'com.ibm.msg.client.wmq'
>   could not be loaded .; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory incompatible with
>   com.ibm.msg.client.provider.ProviderFactoryFactory

Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: This type of error is usually caused by a classpath issue, for example com.ibm.mq.*.jar files from mixed versions of MQ, or missing jars.  7.5 of MQ went out of support 2 years ago in April 2018, the 7.5.0.3 maintenance was released over 6 years ago in February 2014.  I would recommend looking at public maven for [9.1.0.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/9.1.0.5) as a replacement.

Comment: I'm not a JMS guy but aren't you missing a dependency for "com.ibm.mq"?  You should do as JoshMc pointed out and then use the "com.ibm.mq.allclient" artifactId.

Comment: the solution worked. That war works fine with jdk 1.7. I have other wars on the same jboss 4.3 server instance that need jdk 1.6. any ideas?

Comment: MQ at v8 requires Java 1.7.  Can you describe which solution worked?